# How to switch existing Makefile project to CMake in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

I can't figure out how to switch a Makefile project to CMake.

If I open a project from VCS for example, the project might have a Makefile in it already, and CLion will detect this. But there seems to be no way to switch the configuration to CMake afterwards?

I delete the Makefile and add a `CMakelists.txt`, then I edit the debug configuration... but it asks for a 'target', with no options but 'all targets' which doesn't work.
Clicking the 'build' options also still tries to build using a Makefile.

The only workaround I found so far, is to reload the folder as a new project (after deleting the `.idea` folder) and let CLion correctly detect the `CMakelists.txt`, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Does the `CMakeLists.txt` file describe the same project as the makefile or did you just add a `CMakeLists.txt` in the hopes a basically empty one would do the trick? The fact that no targets other than the default one (all) is listed indicates that there were no targets created in your cmake project. (Either that or clion works with build presets...)

Comment: The CMakelist is a working file once I reload the project as described..but I can't figure out how to change the project from a Make to a Cmake type. For example, you can right-click on a CMakelists.txt and pick 'Reload CMake Project'. But that option is missing if you just create a new CMakelists.txt.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the makefile, then navigate to the source directory and delete the `.idea` folder (a hidden folder), then select `invalidate caches` in the `file` tab and restart the IDE. After restarting the IDE, you should be able to reload the CMake project.

Please note that I was unable to find a straightforward method to accomplish this.

Comment: If you want to use CMake and Make at the same time, you can add `<component name="CMakeWorkspace" PROJECT_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR$" />` to `.idea/misc.xml`